# PyQt SQL Query with Bindings

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt, pyqt5, qsqlquery

I'm trying to write an SQL query in PyQt5 that updates some data in a table, but cannot get the query to work. I've read countless forums but as far as I can tell my code is correct. I also have read the documentation back to front so maybe I'm missing something?

I am using PyQt5, python3.5 and SQLITE. The following code (lastError/lastQuery not shown):

```
self.sqlWrite('ct','MarkerSize',123)

def sqlWrite(self,tbl,var,val):
        query = QtSql.QSqlQuery(self.db) # First create query instance.
        # Prepare query with placeholders, then bind values.
        query.prepare('UPDATE :tbl SET value=:val WHERE property=:var')
        query.bindValue(0,tbl)
        query.bindValue(1,val)
        query.bindValue(2,var)
        # Finally execute query.
        query.exec_()
```

...produces the error:

```
near "?": syntax error Unable to execute statement
near "?": syntax error Unable to execute statement
UPDATE :tbl SET value=:val WHERE property=:var
 Parameter count mismatch
```

Have I lost the plot? What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a guess, since I've never used PyQt5: do you need escape characters (single- or double-quotes) around the placeholders in the UPDATE statement for the string values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A table name is not a parameter, so you cannot bind a value to it. Placeholders are intended for use with literal values, not arbitrary strings. For the latter, you should just use normal string interpolation:

```
    query.prepare('UPDATE "%s" SET value=:val WHERE property=:var' % tbl)
    query.bindValue(':val', val)
    query.bindValue(':var', var)
```

For a more generic way to escape identifiers, use the query's [driver](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldriver.html):

```
    tbl = query.driver().escapeIdentifier(tbl, QSqlDriver.TableName)
    query.prepare('UPDATE %s SET value=:val WHERE property=:var' % tbl)
```

Comment: This is perfect. I just assumed the table name was included as a parameter, is this an SQL thing? (My SQL knowledge is very limited).

Comment: @NineTails. Parameters are dynamic *runtime* variables. Identifiers (such as table names) are static and need to be known at *compilation time* (i.e. when the statement is prepared). A prepared statement is like an expression in algebra. Changing the *literal values* of the variables will always give the same kind of result; but changing the *names of the variables* probably won't.